# logging all request and data in server file node.js

Tags: node.js

I have to build a custom logger that logs information about each request it receives. I have to use: Agent,Time,Method,Resource,Version,Status I think I already created my logger and the things i want to to log. now i have to  Expose an endpoint http://localhost:3000/logs that will return a json object with all the logs I dont know how to do it. Help!

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app =  express();

app.use(( req, res, next) => {
    // write your logging code here
    var agent = req.headers('user-agent');
    var time = new Date()
    var method = req.method;
    var baseUrl = req.originalUrl;
    var version = 'HTTP/' + req.httpVersion;
    var status = res.statusCode;
    var allData = agent  + time  +  method  +   baseUrl  +  version + status;

    fs.appendFile('./log.csv', allData, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(allData)
        next()
    })
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // write your code to respond "ok" here
    res.status(200).send('Ok');
});

app.get('/logs', (req, res) => {
    // write your code to return a json object containing the log data here
    fs.readFile('log.csv', 'utf8', (err, data) => {

    });
    module.exports = app;
}
```

Comment: You don't actually generate CSV: `var allData = agent + time + method + baseUrl +  version + status;` produces a string with all the parts combined without any delimiters nor quoting of any parts that might contain those delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson) library. You can use it for csvtojson conversion.

Anyway, consider that if the csv file dimensions grows a lot, reading the whole file and converting it to JSON will be an overkill. Consider a database for a scalable solution.